# Ear-clipping algorithm for non-planar polygons

Tags: computational-geometry

I was looking into the ear-clipping algorithm for triangulating simple polygons. I have successfully implemented it on planar polygons. However if polygon is non-planar the algorithm breaks down. Specifically one step of the algorithm is to test if there're any polygon vertices inside each ear. However point triangle test only makes sense if the point lies in the same plane as the triangle.

So does ear-clipping algorithm not work for non-planar polygons? If so what algorithm could I use instead? I need it to support simple polygons with potentially holes inside them.